# Memory error thrown by the Node_Registration module in the backend

Tags: php, drupal, memory-limit

After installing Drupal and enabling few modules, the Node_Registration module is working fine on the frontend but a memory error is displayed on the backend.

In the php.ini the memory_limit is set to 128M.

Can someone give clue that what could be the reason?

Comment: I improved the wording of the question a bit, so it is easier to find and read and you are more likely to receive an answer. Could you please provide us with the full error message to specify the problem?

Comment: are there any errors showing in the log?

Comment: Node_registration module all related pages are fine but it shows memory error only on setting 

node/32/node_registration/settings

error is : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home/website/url/